# KR exercise 4.7 Ungets function test

Tags: c, string, kernighan-and-ritchie

I need to write a function ungets(s) that will push back an entire string onto the input. I don`t know if the implementation of ungets is right. I have no idea  how to test it, any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Implementation */    

#define BUFSIZE 100
static char buf[BUFSIZE];
static int bufp = 0;             /* next free position in buf */

int getch(void)           /* get a (possibly pushed back) character */
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}


void ungetch(int c)   /* push character back on input  */
{
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}


void ungets(char *s)  
{
    int c;

    for (c = 0; c < strlen(s); c++) 
        ungetch(c);
}
```

Comment: you are not pushing the string in ungets. you pushing c.

Comment: First of all `c` is an integer and you're pushing it onto a `char` array

Answer (score 5):

Your `getch()` and `ungetch()` code look approximately correct (I've not tested them, but they look right). If you are going to report an error, it would be better to report the error on `stderr`, using something similar to:

```
fprintf(stderr, "ungetch: too many characters (could not push back %c)\n", c);
```

You might also think about upgrading `ungetch()` to return a success/failure indication instead of nothing, and then omit the printing from the function; that allows the calling code to decide how to report the error.

The `ungets()` function appears to be pushing a counter value, not a character.  You should also avoid calling `strlen()` in a loop condition; it converts a linear algorithm into a quadratic one.

```
void ungets(const char *s)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = *s++) != '\0')
        ungetch(c);
}
```

The `const` assures the caller that the function doesn't modify the string that is passed.  This code continues pushing back until the end of the string because `ungetch()` doesn't tell it that it is time to stop.  Pass a 20 KiB string in, and it will generate 19.9 KiB messages; probably not a good idea.

---

[Henrik Carlqvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4134321/henrik-carlqvist) makes the astute [observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037301/ungets-function-test/32037547#comment51976131_32037547):

> One more thing to consider is the order in which the characters in the `ungets` string is stored in the buffer and in which order they are read out. As the current `getch` function reads out characters in the reverse order as a stack you probably want to store strings on that stack with the rightmost char first and the leftmost char last.

And, of course, Henrik is right.  So, the code in `ungets()` needs to be upgraded, and needs the string length — or at least has to find the end of the string.

I'm going to assume a variant of the `ungetch()` function that returns an `int`, yielding EOF when there's no space in the buffer and some other value (either zero or the character pushed back, but the code won't care which) when it succeeds, so that the loop can be terminated early if necessary.

The `ungets()` function will also be upgraded to report EOF on error or the number of characters pushed back.

```
int ungets(const char *s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    for (int i = len; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (ungetch(s[i-1]) == EOF)
            return EOF;
    }
    return len;
}
```

I wrote the loop as shown so that if you change `int` to `size_t` (an unsigned type), it still works correctly.  As long as you use a signed integer type, you can use this loop instead:

```
for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (ungetch(s[i]) == EOF)
        return EOF;
}
```

Or use a `while` loop:

```
size_t len = strlen(s);
while (len > 0)
{
    if (ungetch(s[--len]) == EOF)
        return EOF;
}
```

Using signed integers is simpler, but might be more prone to integer overflow issues if the data sizes are large enough (2 GiB or more).  This usually isn't an actual problem; if it is, you are aware of the issue and code accordingly.

---

[tinky_winky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141471/tinky-winky) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037301/ungets-function-test/32037547#comment51977100_32037547):

> Could you provide a test case please?

I suppose so.  This is what I ended up with.  It has more casts in it than I'd like but it compiles cleanly under my default stringent compiling options (source file `ugcs.c`):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIM(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))

extern int getch(void);
extern int ungetch(int c);
extern int ungets_0(const char *s);
extern int ungets_1(const char *s);
extern int ungets_2(const char *s);
extern int ungets_3(const char *s);
extern int ungets_4(const char *s);

/* Implementation */
enum { BUFSIZE = 100 };
static char buf[BUFSIZE];
static int bufp = 0;             /* next free position in buf */

int getch(void)           /* get a (possibly pushed back) character */
{
    assert(bufp >= 0 && bufp <= (int)sizeof(buf));
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

int ungetch(int c)   /* push character back on input  */
{
    if (bufp >= (int)sizeof(buf))
        return EOF;
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
    return c;
}

static void dump_pushback(void)
{
    printf("PBB: L = %d: [%.*s]\n", bufp, bufp, buf);
}

/* Viable but quadratic because of repeated strlen() */
/* Pushes characters in wrong order */
int ungets_0(const char *s)
{
    int c;

    for (c = 0; c < (int)strlen(s); c++)
    {
        // Bogus: if (ungetch(c) == EOF)
        if (ungetch(s[c]) == EOF)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ungetch() failed on %d '%c'\n", c, c);
            dump_pushback();
            return EOF;
        }
    }
    dump_pushback();
    return 0;
}

/* One workable solution */
int ungets_1(const char *s)
{
    int len = (int)strlen(s);
    for (int i = len; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (ungetch(s[i - 1]) == EOF)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ungetch() failed on %d '%c'\n", s[i-1], s[i-1]);
            dump_pushback();
            return EOF;
        }
    }
    dump_pushback();
    return len;
}

/* Using size_t instead of int */
int ungets_2(const char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    for (size_t i = len; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (ungetch(s[i - 1]) == EOF)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ungetch() failed on %d '%c'\n", s[i-1], s[i-1]);
            dump_pushback();
            return EOF;
        }
    }
    dump_pushback();
    return len;
}

/* Only works with signed int */
int ungets_3(const char *s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);

    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (ungetch(s[i]) == EOF)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ungetch() failed on %d '%c'\n", s[len], s[len]);
            dump_pushback();
            return EOF;
        }
    }
    dump_pushback();
    return len;
}

/* Using size_t and a while loop */
int ungets_4(const char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    while (len > 0)
    {
        if (ungetch(s[--len]) == EOF)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ungetch() failed on %d '%c'\n", s[len], s[len]);
            dump_pushback();
            return EOF;
        }
    }
    dump_pushback();
    return len;
}

/*
** ungetters: a constant array of pointers to functions; each function
** returns an int and takes a constant char pointer argument.  In theory,
** the typedef isn't necessary.  In practice, it saves your sanity.
*/
typedef int (*UngetStr)(const char *);
static const UngetStr ungetters[] =
{
    ungets_0, ungets_1, ungets_2,
    ungets_3, ungets_4
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    UngetStr ungets = ungets_1;
    int index;
    if (argc > 1 && (index = atoi(argv[1])) >= 0 && index < (int)DIM(ungetters))
    {
        printf("Using function ungets_%d\n", index);
        ungets = ungetters[index];
    }

    char buffer[32];
    index = 0;
    int i;
    int c;

    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        if ((c = getch()) == EOF)
        {
            printf("%d: got EOF\n", i);
            break;
        }
        printf("%d: got %3d '%c'\n", i, c, (isprint(c) ? c : '.'));
        buffer[index++] = c;
        if (i % 3 == 2)
        {
            printf("%d: ungetting %3d '%c'\n", i, c, (isprint(c) ? c : '.'));
            ungetch(c);
        }
        else if (i % 7 == 6)
        {
            buffer[index/2] = '\0';
            printf("%d: ungetting string [%s]\n", i, buffer);
            ungets(buffer);
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    while ((c = getch()) != EOF)
        printf("%d: got %3d '%c'\n", i++, c, (isprint(c) ? c : '.'));

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation (using GCC 5.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.5):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror ugcs.c -o ugc
$
```

Sample data file (`data`):

```
abcdefg
ABCDEFGHIJKL
```

Sample output from `ugcs < data`:

```
0: got  97 'a'
1: got  98 'b'
2: got  99 'c'
2: ungetting  99 'c'
3: got  99 'c'
4: got 100 'd'
5: got 101 'e'
5: ungetting 101 'e'
6: got 101 'e'
6: ungetting string [abc]
PBB: L = 3: [cba]
7: got  97 'a'
8: got  98 'b'
8: ungetting  98 'b'
9: got  98 'b'
10: got  99 'c'
11: got 102 'f'
11: ungetting 102 'f'
12: got 102 'f'
13: got 103 'g'
13: ungetting string [abb]
PBB: L = 3: [bba]
14: got  97 'a'
14: ungetting  97 'a'
15: got  97 'a'
16: got  98 'b'
17: got  98 'b'
17: ungetting  98 'b'
18: got  98 'b'
19: got  10 '.'
20: got  65 'A'
20: ungetting  65 'A'
21: got  65 'A'
22: got  66 'B'
23: got  67 'C'
23: ungetting  67 'C'
24: got  67 'C'
25: got  68 'D'
26: got  69 'E'
26: ungetting  69 'E'
27: got  69 'E'
27: ungetting string [aabbb
A]
PBB: L = 7: [A
bbbaa]
28: got  97 'a'
29: got  97 'a'
29: ungetting  97 'a'
30: got  97 'a'
31: got  98 'b'
32: got  98 'b'
32: ungetting  98 'b'
33: got  98 'b'
34: got  98 'b'
34: ungetting string [aaa]
PBB: L = 5: [A
aaa]
35: got  97 'a'
35: ungetting  97 'a'
36: got  97 'a'
37: got  97 'a'
38: got  97 'a'
38: ungetting  97 'a'
39: got  97 'a'
40: got  10 '.'
41: got  65 'A'
42: got  70 'F'
43: got  71 'G'
44: got  72 'H'
45: got  73 'I'
46: got  74 'J'
47: got  75 'K'
48: got  76 'L'
49: got  10 '.'
$
```

Testing all the algorithms:

```
$ for i in $(seq 0 4); do ugcs $i < data > ugcs-$i.out; done
$ ls -l ugcs-?.out 
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  1286 Aug 16 14:42 ugcs-0.out
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  1286 Aug 16 14:42 ugcs-1.out
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  1286 Aug 16 14:42 ugcs-2.out
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  1286 Aug 16 14:42 ugcs-3.out
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  1286 Aug 16 14:42 ugcs-4.out
$ diff ugcs-1.out ugcs-2.out
1c1
< Using function ungets_1
---
> Using function ungets_2
$ diff ugcs-1.out ugcs-3.out
1c1
< Using function ungets_1
---
> Using function ungets_3
$ diff ugcs-1.out ugcs-4.out
1c1
< Using function ungets_1
---
> Using function ungets_4
$ diff ugcs-0.out ugcs-4.out
1c1
< Using function ungets_0
---
> Using function ungets_4
12,13c12,13
< PBB: L = 3: [abc]
< 7: got  99 'c'
---
> PBB: L = 3: [cba]
> 7: got  97 'a'
17c17
< 10: got  97 'a'
---
> 10: got  99 'c'
22,26c22,26
< 13: ungetting string [cbb]
< PBB: L = 3: [cbb]
< 14: got  98 'b'
< 14: ungetting  98 'b'
< 15: got  98 'b'
---
> 13: ungetting string [abb]
> PBB: L = 3: [bba]
> 14: got  97 'a'
> 14: ungetting  97 'a'
> 15: got  97 'a'
28,30c28,30
< 17: got  99 'c'
< 17: ungetting  99 'c'
< 18: got  99 'c'
---
> 17: got  98 'b'
> 17: ungetting  98 'b'
> 18: got  98 'b'
43c43
< 27: ungetting string [bbbcc
---
> 27: ungetting string [aabbb
45,54c45,54
< PBB: L = 7: [bbbcc
< A]
< 28: got  65 'A'
< 29: got  10 '.'
< 29: ungetting  10 '.'
< 30: got  10 '.'
< 31: got  99 'c'
< 32: got  99 'c'
< 32: ungetting  99 'c'
< 33: got  99 'c'
---
> PBB: L = 7: [A
> bbbaa]
> 28: got  97 'a'
> 29: got  97 'a'
> 29: ungetting  97 'a'
> 30: got  97 'a'
> 31: got  98 'b'
> 32: got  98 'b'
> 32: ungetting  98 'b'
> 33: got  98 'b'
56,70c56,67
< 34: ungetting string [A
< 
< ]
< PBB: L = 5: [bbA
< 
< ]
< 35: got  10 '.'
< 35: ungetting  10 '.'
< 36: got  10 '.'
< 37: got  10 '.'
< 38: got  65 'A'
< 38: ungetting  65 'A'
< 39: got  65 'A'
< 40: got  98 'b'
< 41: got  98 'b'
---
> 34: ungetting string [aaa]
> PBB: L = 5: [A
> aaa]
> 35: got  97 'a'
> 35: ungetting  97 'a'
> 36: got  97 'a'
> 37: got  97 'a'
> 38: got  97 'a'
> 38: ungetting  97 'a'
> 39: got  97 'a'
> 40: got  10 '.'
> 41: got  65 'A'
$
```

Comment: One more thing to consider is the order in which the characters in the ungets string is stored in the buffer and in which order they are read out. As the current getch function reads out characters in the reverse order as a stack you probably want to store strings on that stack with the rightmost char first and the leftmost char last.

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist: Thanks.  You're correct.  I've updated the answer to deal with that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler could you provide a test case please?

Comment: @tinky_winky: Since you ask so nicely — see my update.  It isn't trivial C, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you very much. Good lesson of C programming with test-suite.

Comment: Other wisely good but I can`t read the source. It would require the whole code commented, or alternatively I can return to the code after studying pointers and arrays.

Comment: @user004325: The test code can be simplified by: (1) Choosing a single implementation of `ungets()` and calling it `ungets()`; (2) Removing the array of pointers to functions and the variable `ungets`, and using just `int main(void)`.  What's left then calls `getch()` quite often, and `ungetch()` sometimes, and `ungets()` occasionally, which is the code that needs to be tested.  You can devise other techniques for making those calls as you wish.  The dump function is a useful debugging aid; I usually have a similar function for any data structure that might need analysis.

Comment: Sorry, I don`t understand the dump function.

Comment: @user004325: Hmmm...it's a single [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) call: `printf("PBB: L = %d: [%.*s]\n", bufp, bufp, buf);`  The only thing that's possibly confusing in that is the `%.*s` conversion.  If it said `%.10s`, it would print up to 10 characters of the string.  The `*` means 'take the length from an `int` argument', which is why the second value `bufp` is passed to `printf()`.  The square brackets simply make it easier to see the ends of the string; it can help if you have trailing blanks or embedded backspaces or carriage returns.

Comment: Wouldn`t a debugger serve the same purpose?

Comment: Yes, no, sort of.  Yes, if you run the code under a debugger, you could get the information.  No, because I don't run programs under a debugger all that often.  A function like that can be used even when not using a debugger.  I didn't run the test program under a debugger; I don't often need to use one.  But I do need, and therefore write and use, debugging output.   For more complex structures, a dump function controls the output format better than a debugger does.  And a general purpose dump function takes a "tag" string and a file stream and can be used for logging to file, etc.

Answer (score 1):

this code will do the work,

```
void ungets(char *s)
  {
    int length = strlen(s);
    while(length>0)
       ungetch(s[--length]);
  }
```

Comment: This isn’t C89 any more, you can initialise a variable upon declaration. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: you could do that in pre-standard C too!

Comment: I read from [K&R solutions](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_4:Exercise_7) . explanation also given there.

Comment: May i know how this could be a wrong answer ? it works for me.

Comment: How about test driver?

Comment: Given the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037301/ungets-function-test#comment51976131_32037547) made by [Henrik Carlqvist](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4134321/henrik-carlqvist) to my answer, this is now correct (because it uses `ungetch()` rather than `ungetc()` now).